# Type safe numeric constants in C++

Tags: c++

Let's say you start off coding a project, and certain types are integers, i.e. you code might look like this:

```
typedef int NumericType;
NumericType a = 0;
NumericType b = 100;
```

Down the road you change CountingType to a special class, that doesn't have an implicit cast from integer for safety reasons. Now, you have to go through all of your code and update places where you used constants. I've started to go through my code to change it to this:

```
typedef specialType NumericType;
NumericType a = static_cast<NumericType>(0);
NumericType b = static_cast<NumericType>(100);
```

This way if I change the NumericType again in  the future, I'd have less code to change. I've started to wonder if this is one of those rules that I should start following in general, in that I should always static_cast constants.

I've started to do that anytime that I use format strings in C++ so that if I change types, I have some chance of getting a warning for my sprintf_s calls. i.e.

```
sprintf_s(buffer, 10, "Bob %d", static_cast<int>(bob));
```

Is there another pattern for handling constants and typing?

Comment: I'd say, this leads to a lot of unsafety. Explicit casts turn off compiler warnings which might be important and help you spot a logic error. Every time I see an explicit cast, I am always wondering why we have it there.

Comment: Why not add the two functions needed for implicit conversions?  `class NumericType { NumericType(int v) : m_value(v) {} operator int() const { return m_value; } };`

Comment: I'd say it's a double edged blade. With `printf` function family, you avoid undefined behaviour if `bob` is not an int. Some compilers spot this, though (e. g. GCC does so) and emit a warning if type does not match – unless you force the type to match, losing this warning then. But if size of `bob` is larger than `int`, you silently lose the most significant bytes perhaps without even noticing – and then wondering about strange outputs.

Comment: @Wyck As far as I understood the question, these *do* exist, but are declared `explicit` because of implicit casts being undesired? On the other hand, I'd delcare the variables then rather as `NumericType n(7);`...

Comment: For type safe numeric constants I like to use `enum class`'s and `inline constexpr` variables.  This does mean you can't use the `printf` family of functions without casting but nothing is perfect.  If you switch to using streams you can overload the stream operators for the `enum class`'s.  You could switch to using [boost format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) if you want a type safe printf like utility.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to some other developers in my group and another solution, which I like, is to use a code like this:

```
typedef int NumericType;
NumericType a = NumericType(0);
NumericType b = NumericType(100);
```

The benefit of this is that if I switch the type for NumericType, I just have to make sure that it can be constructed with int, which is different than letting it be convertable to int. i.e. this code works when only the typedef is updated, as long as `specialType` has a constructor that takes an `int` or a `long`.

```
typedef specialType NumericType;
NumericType a = NumericType(0);
NumericType b = NumericType(100);
```